# C++/CLI Linker Error LNK2022 when targeting .net5

Tags: c++-cli

We are converting a set of C++/CLI projects from vs2017 targeting .netframework 471 to vs2019 targeting .net5.

The following code will compile and link when targeting .netframework471, but will generate a linker error when targeting .net5.  Note that it seems to be only the method which uses gcrootSystem::String^, when the method foobar is commented out the project builds and links successfully (meaning that the foobar2 method with the gcrootSystem::Exception^ parameter does not cause a problem).

> 1>MSVCMRTD_netcore.LIB(mstartup.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata
> operation failed (80131195) :
> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors

```
// UnmanagedClassWithGcHandle.h
#pragma once
#include <vcclr.h>

class UnmanagedClassWithGcHandle
{
public:
   int age;
   // error LNK2022 : metadata operation failed(80131195) :  ( ONLY TARGETING .NET 5.0 )
   void foobar(gcroot<System::String^>);

   // this is successful
   void foobar2(gcroot<System::Exception^>);
};

#include "pch.h"
#include "UnmanagedClassWithGcHandle.h"

// UnamanagedClassWithCcHandle.cpp
void UnmanagedClassWithGcHandle::foobar(gcroot<System::String^>)
{
}

void UnmanagedClassWithGcHandle::foobar2(gcroot<System::Exception^>)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem. The problem is with:

```
#include <vcclr.h>
```

This is the old file for accessing `gcroot`. Instead you need to:

```
#include <msclr/gcroot.h>
```

This will bring in the `gcroot` that is in the `msclr` namespace. Change your code to:

```
void foobar(msclr::gcroot<System::String^>);
```

And you should be able to build.